# What will be the complexity of the function having two input sizes?

Tags: complexity

What will be the complexities in the following case:

T(m,n) = T(m-1,n) + T(n-1,m) + O(m*n)

After a bit of searching I found that if I could make this function monotonic and then try to find the solution. But I am feeling that this is not the correct way to do it.

Kindly suggest the solution to it.

Comment: Is "(2 Marks)" an actual mathematical part of the equality, or only a meta information specifying what you get for answering correctly this question of the quiz? - - - - -  What do you want monotonic with respect to what?

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: The OP did try something.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Computer Science StackExchange. This question has a lot of potential to be a great question for this site. As it is, however, it's a bit hard to understand exactly what you're asking: for instance, are you asking how the solution in two variables was determined, or are you asking how one might eliminate one of the variables in the above expression? What is "f"? Please feel free to edit this question to provide a bit more detail, at which point you should flag this question so that it can be reopened and answered. Thanks for your patience, and again, welcome!

Comment: Now I have edited this to make it more clearer